# ejb3 persistence and javax persistence jar files in classpath?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, jpa

I am using spring3 and Hibernate4 JPA application. 
I have below two jars in my classpath.

```
ejb3-persistence-1.0.2.GA.jar
 Javax.persistence jar version 1.0.2
```

Do i need both the jars? why these jars are required?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either one of this jar. These jars contains JPA API classes only. No specific implementation logic.
If you use maven(gradle, ivy), no need to include this jar since you have added hibernate dependency. Maven will automatically include dependent jars of your project dependent jars.